# problems looping with fastLink

Tags: r

First of all, sorry for my English, I'm translating with google translator

I have two df to which I apply fastLink

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c("pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaB","pruebaB","pruebaB"),col2=c("avion","casa","coche","verde","antonio","jardin"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
df2<-data.frame(col1=c("pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaB","pruebaB","pruebaA"),col2=c("avion","casa grande","coche rojo","Berde","antoñito","jardinn"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(fastLink)


prueba <- function(d1, d2) {
  out <- fastLink(
    dfA = d1, dfB = d2,
    varnames = c("col1","col2"),
    partial.match = c("col2"),
    stringdist.match = c("col2")
  )
  indi<<- out$matches
  dfA.match <<- d1[out$matches$inds.a,]
}

prueba(df1,df2)
```

I get `indi` and `dfA.match` so I can query them.

How could I do the same when I have a lot of df?
I can't make a loop

For example,
I divide df1 and df2 into parts

```
df1$M <- paste0(df1$col1, "_df1")
z <- split(df1,df1$M )

list2env(z, .GlobalEnv)


df2$M <- paste0(df2$col1,"_df2")
b <- split(df2,df2$M )

list2env(b, .GlobalEnv)
```

I get

```
-PruebaA_df1
-PruebaA_df2
-PruebaB_df1
-PruebaB_df1

prueba(pruebaA_df1,pruebaA_df2)
prueba(pruebaB_df1,pruebaB_df2)
```

works!

Same with a loop

```
unique(df1$col1)->nom2b

indices<- list()
uniones<- list()
for (i in nom2b){
  d1<-paste0(i,"_df1")
  d2<-paste0(i,"_df2")
  #cat(d1)->d1
  #cat(d2)->d2
  prueba(d1,d2)
  indices[[paste0("modelo",i)]]<-indi
  uniones[[paste0("uniones",i)]]<- dfA.match 
}
```

Wrong!!, it doesn't work!!

Comment: So it already works with `split` and `list2env` for you. You are now trying to make it work using `for` loop?

Comment: I use split and list2env to get the data:                                                                pruebaA_df1, pruebaA_df2........pruebaA_df1000 .                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                  I'm looking for a way to put that data in the "Prueba" function: 
prueba(pruebaA_df1, pruebaA_df2........pruebaA_df1000)  and not have to write by hand

Comment: the same example, but easier to understand,
I will delete this question                                                                                                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812662/looping-with-fastlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have objects called `pruebaA_df1`, `pruebaA_df2` .... `pruebaA_df1000` in your environment, you can use `Reduce` as :

```
result <- Reduce(prueba, mget(paste0('pruebaA_df', 1:1000)))
```

Comment: > result <- do.call(prueba, mget(paste0('pruebaA_df', 1:2)))
                                                                                                                                           Error in (function (d1, d2)  : 
  unused arguments (pruebaA_df1 = list(c("pruebaA", "pruebaA", "pruebaA"), c("avion", "casa", "coche"), c("pruebaA_df1", "pruebaA_df1", "pruebaA_df1")), pruebaA_df2 = list(c("pruebaA", "pruebaA", "pruebaA", "pruebaA"), c("avion", "casa grande", "coche rojo", "jardinn"), c("pruebaA_df2", "pruebaA_df2", "pruebaA_df2", "pruebaA_df2")))

Comment: a<-mget(paste0('pruebaA_df', 1:2))[1]
b<-mget(paste0('pruebaA_df', 1:2))[2]
                                                                                                                                             prueba(a,b)---> Error                                                                                                                   prueba(a$pruebaA_df1,b$pruebaA_df2)---> ok, work

Comment: @DudaR How does the `prueba` function actually work? In the ear;lier comment you mentioned as `prueba(pruebaA_df1, pruebaA_df2........pruebaA_df1000)` and now you are mentioning it as `prueba(a$pruebaA_df1,b$pruebaA_df2)`

Comment: It should work like this
prueba(pruebaA_df1,pruebaA_df2)
But your answer only works if I put it like this

prueba(a$pruebaA_df1,b$pruebaA_df2)

Comment: What happens if you use my code as it is? Does it give you any error? What is it?

Comment: Yes, it gives me an error, I put it as the first comment

Comment: Ohh..I see. Can you try `result <- Reduce(prueba, mget(paste0('pruebaA_df', 1:1000)))`

Comment: ok, it works!
Now I have to modify it to work with

pruebaB_df1....
pruebaC_df1.....

Thanks a lot